# Tinymce 5 - Apply the style format from the listed

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I want to apply two custom style formats called:

- Custom format 1
- Custom format 2

When TinyMCE completes loading the editor, the default paragraph style is applied. I want to set Custom format 1 as the default style, and if the existing data already has a different style, that style should be applied instead.

I have searched through the documentation but couldn't find the appropriate command. What is the correct command to select a style format from the list as the default?

https://codepen.io/jeeva-jsb/pen/XWyKPeZ

```
tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',
      height: 500,cache_suffix: '?v=5.2.3',
      default_block: 'p',
          style_formats: [
            {
              title: 'Custom format1',
              block: 'p',
              attributes: { class: 'ms-custom-1' },
            },
            {
              title: 'Custom format 2',
              block: 'p',
              attributes: { class: 'ms-custom-2' },
            }
          ],
    });
```

I have tried the following solution,

```
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('init', function() {
      var defaultStyle = 'ms-custom-1'; // Change this to the desired default style class
      var content = editor.getContent();
      
      // Check if the content already has a different style class applied
      var regex = /class="(.*?)"/g;
      var match = regex.exec(content);
      
      if (match && match[1]) {
        // Content has a style class applied, update defaultStyle to the matched class
        defaultStyle = match[1];
      }
      
      // Apply the default style format
      editor.formatter.apply(defaultStyle);
    });
  }
```

But I am getting the following error in the console

[image: Console error]